# Python throwing OverflowError with Unexpected behavior during an addition operation

Tags: python

I am trying to make a calculator app where the user can enter their name, then they get a message saying hello with their name and how many letters in their name, then they can enter numbers and the operator to perform a specific mathematical operation.

Everything is working fine except for a weird behavior happening when trying to add bigger numbers like 2000+1000, it throws an error like such

```
'**' : [num_1 ** num_2, "your operation is power"]
OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')
```

although the operation was addition, the exponential operation was referenced in the error somehow, which I do not understand why it happened

and here is the code

```py
def main():
    hello_user()
    calculator()

def calculator():
    check_type(calculate())
    restart()

def hello_user():
    while True:
        name = input("Enter your name using a-z characters: ")
        name_length = len(name) - name.count(' ') 
        if len(name) != 0 and name.replace(' ', '').isalpha():
            print(f"Hello {name.title()}, your name consists of {name_length} letters")
            break
        else:
            print("please use only letters, try again.")
            continue

def calculate():
    while True:
        try:
            num_1 = float(input("Enter 1st number: "))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("please only enter a number, try again.")
            continue

    while True:
        try:
            num_2 = float(input("Enter 2nd number: "))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("please only enter a number, try again.")
            continue

    while True:            
        operator = input("Enter one of these operators (+ - / * **) : ")
        if operator not in ['+', '-', '/', '*', '**']:
            print("please enter a correct operator, try again.")
            continue
        else:
            break
    
    results = {
        '+' : [num_1 + num_2, "your operation is addition"],
        '-' : [num_1 - num_2, "your operation is subtraction"],
        '*' : [num_1 * num_2, "your operation is multiplication"],
        '/' : [num_1 / num_2, "your operation is division"],
        '**' : [num_1 ** num_2, "your operation is power"]
    }
    
    result = results[operator][0]
    result_string = results[operator][1]
    return [result, result_string]

def check_type(List):
    res = List[0]
    str_res = str(res)
    res_type = "unknown"
    after_point = str_res.split(".")[1]
    
    if len(after_point) > 1 or (len(after_point) == 1 and after_point != '0'):
        res_type = "float"
    else:
        if res % 2 == 0:
            res_type = "even"
        else:
            res_type = "odd"

    print(f"the result is {res} and {List[1]} and the type is {res_type}") 

def restart():
    choice = input("do you wish to perform another operation, please enter Y to continue, any other entry quits the program: ")
    if choice.lower() == 'y':
        calculator()
    else:
        print("thank you and goodbye.")   


main()
```

if i eliminate this line from the dictionary it works fine

```
'**' : [num_1 ** num_2, "your operation is power"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that those bits of code get evaluated right away, that's how eager computation works. You can delay execution of things by using functions, for example:

```
import operator

(...)
    
    results = {
        '+' : [operator.add, "your operation is addition"],
        '-' : [operator.sub, "your operation is subtraction"],
        '*' : [operator.mul, "your operation is multiplication"],
        '/' : [operator.truediv, "your operation is division"],
        '**' : [operator.pow, "your operation is power"]
    }
    
    op, result_string = results[operator]
    return [op(num_1, num_2), result_string]
```

(As an aside, these fixed length lists you got should really be tuples).

Comment: thank you now i understand!, and with that small change all my code still works as intended

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your code is executing `num1 ** num2`, even if the user doesn't type in '**'.  Your calculating all of the results of the five possible calculations, putting them in a table, and then pulling out the result you want.  Needless to say, with large values you're going to get overflow.

You're better off putting operators in your table:

First change your variable `operator` to `op`, since operator is the name of the package you'll want to import.

```
import operator
operators = {
    '+: operator.add, 
    '-': operator.sub,
    '*': operator.mul,
    '/': operator.truediv,   # decide if you want truediv or floordiv
    '**': operator.pow
}

result = operators[op](num1, num2)
```

Now, the value is only calculated for the specific operator that the user requests.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have an obvious overflow situation.  For every pair of inputs, you compute *all five* operations, regardless of what the user requested.  Unless *all five* operations complete successfully, your user gets a crash.  This will also stop you from adding 0 to anything, as the division will fail.

```
results = {
    '+' : [num_1 + num_2, "your operation is addition"],
    '-' : [num_1 - num_2, "your operation is subtraction"],
    '*' : [num_1 * num_2, "your operation is multiplication"],
    '/' : [num_1 / num_2, "your operation is division"],
    '**' : [num_1 ** num_2, "your operation is power"]
}
```

Stop that.  Compute only the requested operation.

Comment: thank you for pointing that out! it almost drove me crazy

Comment: You're welcome.  It was easy for me to find, because "crazy" is a short walk from here.